# Getting updated packages list in python at runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have installed a new package using 'pip' within python by executing following command.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install','--ignore-installed','setuptools'])
```

My requirement is to get the updated list of packages at runtime, is it possible to get it ?

Please find the option/ command I have tried. These commands displays the same list of packages which was presented earlier.

```
import imp
imp.reload(pip.utils.pkg_resources)
["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.utils.pkg_resources.working_set]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used latest version of pip (7.1.2), to execute the above commands and that worked. Now, I could able to get the list packages dynamically within python module :)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this to get the current version of the package:

`pip install --no-deps --no-install requests -v`

`Downloading/unpacking requests
  Using version 2.7.0 (newest of versions: 2.7.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.2, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.3, 2.5.2, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.5.0, 2.4.3, 2.4.3, 2.4.2, 2.4.2, 2.4.1, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.13.9, 0.13.8, 0.13.7, 0.13.6, 0.13.5, 0.13.4, 0.13.3, 0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.2, 0.11.1, 0.10.8, 0.10.7, 0.10.6, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.6, 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.6, 0.7.5, 0.7.4, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.6, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0)`

This output gives you an info about the current version, so it means that you can save the version inside your script and execute this command later. if the version will change that you can install new package.